# How to dynamically access object property in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I've been going through and trying to convert existing projects (from Node.js) to TypeScript.

For context, I'm using the http-status package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-status)

I'm trying to pass variables through into their default export, but it's getting an error:

```
import status = require("http-status");

status.OK; // this works
status["OK"] // this also works

let str = "OK";
status[str]; // error
```

**Error:**

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'HttpStatus'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'HttpStatus'.

---

How would I convert this usage to TypeScript?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

`"OK"` is a string, and `str` is implicitly taking the type string in your code.

When you try to access an object's property, you need to use a type `keyof`. TypeScript then knows you are not assigning a random string; you are assigning strings compatible with the properties (keys) for the object.

Also, since `status` is a variable, not a type, you need to extract its type with `typeof`.

Try:

```
let str = "OK" as keyof typeof status;
status[str]; // 200
```

or more cleanly:

```
type StatusKey = keyof typeof status;
let str: StatusKey = "OK";
status[str]; // 200

// and to answer the question about reversal
status[status.OK as StatusKey]; // OK
```

See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types

Comment: Thanks, though I'm getting further issues. status.OK returns a number of 200, however a string of "200" exists as a key on the status object. How would I convert one to the other? So the function (due to your answer) is correctly requiring a string of 200, doing String(status.OK) doesn't seem to satisfy this.

Comment: You can cast the first answer with `as StatusKey`. It's still not a String, it's a StatusKey, tell TypeScript that.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. thanks to your answer, I was able to resolve a blocker that was bugging me for the last 3-4 days!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: `const str = "OK";`   
Is easiest & most readable

Comment: in the case where you want to use 'this', the syntax is: "let str = "OK" as keyof this;"
No need for typeof when using this.  This was my use case to reduce writing lots of duplicate code

Comment: Lots of searching and this was what I needed. Loving TS more and more every day. Although this is a bit verbose, I know why it needs to be. Still awesome. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

I had to access second level dynamic key from an object.

```
const myObj = {
  "address": {
    "street": "Main ave",
    "city": "NYC"
  }
}

secondLevelDynamic(field: string) {

  let dynamicKey = field as keyof myObj;

  let myProp = this.myObj['address'];
  let myDynamicPropValue = myProp[dynamciKey]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually there's a simpler fix, you just have to just use [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions).

Here's the fix:

```
const str = "OK" as const; // <-- add "as const", now `str` has type of "OK" instead of `string`
status[str]; // No more error!
```

[Playground link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBADzgXjgb2HLcDyBpALjgCJjgBfYBAOnwG44B6RuGACwEso4B3MAJwDWUKgG1i+YgF0mLdlzgBDADZQwvAcODBlAU3ix+KEpKXdw0GHTGGpDZnABy63f34CgA)

Comment: `const str = "OK"` is a more elegant way to write this. If OP asked how to do it with a dynamic variable, he probably won't want a constant.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem when I wanted to implement an express patch request on a resource. I wanted to parse through the request body and update only which are specified in the body.

Following is the demo code which I found to be working by using TypeScript Generics.

```
interface ObjType {
  name: string,
  addr: string
}

const demo: ObjType = {
  name: "Foo",
  addr: "Bar"
}

const keyList: Array<keyof ObjType> = ["name", "addr"]

const keyListFromObject: Array<keyof ObjType> = Object.keys({ name: "John", addr: "Alexandria" }) as Array<keyof ObjType>
keyList.forEach((el) => console.log(demo[el]))

keyListFromObject.forEach((el) => console.log(demo[el]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const obj = {
  name: 'Bobby Hadz',
  country: 'Chile',
};

// ️ type ObjectKey = "name" | "country"
type ObjectKey = keyof typeof obj;

const myVar = 'name' as ObjectKey;

console.log(obj[myVar]); // ️ Bobby Hadz
```